# Adding HTML Markup to a WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: php, wordpress, wysiwyg

Many of my blog posts have been imported into the WordPress WYSIWYG editor with HTML Markup/Styles styles. This has resulted in a conflict as the Markdown styles are not recognized, and everything is parsed within paragraph tags.

Is there a way to update the WordPress WYSIWYG to recognize Markdown styles, in order to process the preferred styles - without needing to edit each blog post itself?

Answer (score 1):

You could us a search/replace plugin to replace the markdown with html. That's what markdown produces, anyway. For instance, ** could become . However, the closing ** would be harder to pin down. Here's a link for some plugins that do it, too.
    https://www.sitepoint.com/the-best-markdown-plugins-for-wordpress/